# Socket Programming in ASP.NET?

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, sockets

Can we do Socket Programming in ASP.NET/WCF? Like the service listens on a port for incoming requests. All the clients from outside the network also publish/listen on that ip:port

Whenever the service writes anything on the port, all the clients get that thing without polling.

Is something like this possible with ASP.NET/WCF?

Thanks

Comment: Curious, why would you want to do socket programming in a website?

Comment: The thing is I have developed a C# based desktop server that listens to incoming requests on my cloud server. This binds to the port on local ip. My cloud infrastructure provider refuses to transfer requests coming in on public-ip:port_no to local-ip:port_no where the server is bound to listen. And I can't even bind my server application to listen on a publi-ip!

Comment: @CharlesBoyung, for what it's worth, we have to communicate with a Korean service called MACCO for e-commerce. Their interface is socket-based. Weird, wild stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about WCF/ASP.NET, those two are much "higher" above the socket level.
Answering you question - yes, you can do socket programming with .NET framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx

**EDIT**

BTW, I smell something wrong then hear "sockets.. cloud", you are probably missing something. Taking into account avaliable techlologices for distributed/networking programming doing socket programming nowadays seems illogical.

Comment: I agree that a lot of things that used to require socket programming are no longer needed to be coded by hand, but I disagree that socket programming is completely illogical.

Answer (score 2):

As alexanderb linked, there is indeed .NET socket support in the System.Net.Sockets namespace. As I just completed, with a colleague, a WCF web service that communicates with a socket-based service in Korea. We're simply sending some info and getting some info back, quick, tidy. Here's an example of some sockety code:

```
const string ipAddressString = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx";// replace with correct IP address
IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(ipAddressString);
const int portNum = 1234;// replace with correct port
IPEndPoint remoteEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, portNum);

Socket client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
client.Connect(remoteEndPoint);
string sendString = "some stuff you want to send";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sendString.ToString());
client.Send(bytes);
byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[128];
client.Receive(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length, SocketFlags.None);
string bufferString = Encoding.GetEncoding(949).GetString(receiveBufferSize);
client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
client.Close();
```

try-catches and such have been omitted to keep this as "simple" and socket-focused as possible. The key takeaways here are the Socket construction, `Connect()`, `Send()`, and `Receive()`. Also, `Shutdown()` and `Close()`. Note that before about three days ago, I thought a socket was that thing on the wall you plug stuff into, so this should be fairly rudimentary. But hey, it works!

Comment: Note the GetEncoding(949), that is for Korean characters and you'd more likely use something like "Encoding.UTF8.GetString(...)"

Comment: Edited your post: the socket support is in .NET, not ASP.NET.

Comment: You're right, a subtle but important difference, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do would not work even if you really could do socket programming in Asp.Net. Asp.Net is not continuously "running" like a service is. It shuts down after a period of inactivity (no web requests made) and starts up again with new web requests. Your socket code would only run from when a web request made until that inactivity timeout occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need WCF or ASP.NET for that. You might look up UDP socket programming with .NET.

Comment: The thing is I have developed a C# based desktop server that listens to incoming requests on my cloud server. This binds to the port on local ip. My cloud infrastructure provider refuses to transfer requests coming in on public-ip:port_no to local-ip:port_no where the server is bound to listen. And I can't even bind my server application to listen on a publi-ip!